# Resources for learning Spring.NET

Tags: .net, spring.net

Are there any good online resources (including commercial) or books for learning Spring.NET? The only resources I found are examples and documentation on [Spring.NET web](http://www.springframework.net/examples.html). Is it enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only guide available is the Spring.NET website, I only know of one book (Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns: With Examples in C# and .NET) where it is mentioned and that, along with other resources, is listed on the Spring.NET website which can be found [here](http://www.springframework.net/documentation.html).

In an upcoming book Dependency Injection there's also a topic on Spring.NET, it's currently available through the [MEAP](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) program.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of Spring books out there, but the ones I know about all deal with the Java version.

I'm not aware of any .NET specific versions.  Amazon brought back [these](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=spring.net&x=0&y=0).  The one book devoted to Spring.NET is out of print with limited availability.

I'm not sure how well Spring.NET is doing as a framework.  It's got to get over the "not from Microsoft, not Enterprise Framework" hurdle.

I love it on the Java side; not sure that it's diffusing into the .NET world rapidly.

Comment: I guess The definitive guide to Spring for .NET was never released. Apress doesn't have it on its web pages. Book has no reviews on amazon and nobody sells it on ebay. Other books do not cover Spring.NET - I have them.

Comment: The only guide available is the Spring.NET website, I only know of one book where it is mentioned and that, along with other resources, is listed on the Spring.NET website. http://www.springframework.net/documentation.html